# apache allowoverride points to wrong location

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http

I installed a Slim framework to create a API and located this under

```
 /opt/modul/www/api
    index.php
    slim/
```

so the index.php is my main API file.
And I want to access this in the browser under the URL **localhost/mo/api**

to enable the rewrite mode I created a  **/opt/modul/www/api/.httacces** file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and put to http.conf

```
Alias /mo /opt/modul/www

<Directory /opt/modul/www>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

but if I access the URL localhost/mo/api in the browser I see in error.log

```
File does not exist: /var/www/html/opt
```

why it still looks in /var/www/html? I know, this i a document_root, but is the alias not overwrite it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I point the `RewriteRule` to the absolute location of index.php, based on the ALIAS.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mo/api/index.php [QSA,L]
```